# Yii can't rename/move an uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, properties, file-rename

My controller `Sitecontroller.php`, view file `upload_new.php`, model is `Resume_edit.php`.

I got this error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\yii\jobsite_orginal\protected\controllers\SiteController.php on line 406*

**Sitecontroller.php**

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller
 {
  public function actionupload_new()
  {
   $user_id = 97;
   $jobProfileM2 = new Resume_edit();
 $jobProfileM2 = Resume_edit::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => $user_id));
   if(isset($_POST['Resume_edit']))
      {
        $jobProfileM2->attributes = $_POST['Resume_edit'];
        $jobProfileM2->user_id = $user_id;
        if($jobProfileM2->save())
           {
            $jobProfileM2->user_id = $user_id;
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', "Resume Updated Successfully!");
       $time=time();                                                                         $filename=CUploadedFile::getInstance($jobProfileM2,'resume');
$filename2=explode('.',$filename);
            $filename3=$filename2[0].$time.'.'.$filename2[1];

            $jobProfileM2->resume=$filename3;
            if($jobProfileM2->save())
               {
          $jobProfileM2->resume->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../resume/'.$filename3);
               }
           } 
         else 
            {
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "Error,Canot save Data!");
            }
     }
   $this->render('upload_new', array('model' => $jobProfileM2));
 }
     }
?>
```

**view-upload_new.php**

```
 <div class="form">
   <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true
),
   )); ?>

 <?php
 foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
  }
?>
<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
 <div class="row">
 <?php
 echo $form->labelEx($model, 'resume');
 echo $form->fileField($model, 'resume');
 echo $form->error($model, 'resume');
?>
 </div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
 </div>
```

This is line 406:

```
 $jobProfileM2->resume->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../resume/'.$filename3);
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

`resume` is a property of your model `Resume_edit`, and properties do not have a function `saveAs()`.

If you want to move/rename files, use the [`rename()`](https://www.php.net/rename) method.

```
$newFileName = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../resume/'.$filename3;
@rename($jobProfileM2->resume, $newFileName);
$jobProfileM2->resume = $filename3;
```